# What happens after you choose the Pagan secret ending?

Tags: far-cry-4

What type of Epilogue do you get after you side with Pagan (During the very beginning of the game.) Do you just go to open world after you normally beat the game. Or is there something else?

Comment: I didn't really cared for the Tagging thing. I did it on purpose because I kind of found it useless. To me its shows no purpose for even asking a question. I don't know what you guys think. But i just did it so i could post my question.

Comment: @JoePa the tagging system is to let users know what game the question is related to.

Comment: How would we (aside from meme scientist) have known what game you're talking about if it didn't have the right tag?

Comment: Trust me, i was going to tag it as Fry Cry 4. But it wouldn't let me for some reason.

Comment: It's `far-cry-4` not `fry-cry-4`, although the latter sounds kinda funny

Comment: Arqade works much better the more effort you put in.  Users respond to that effort, and provide you with good answers.  You demonstrate a lack of effort, though...and don't expect us to really be all that willing to help you.  Put more in, get more out.  It's a win-win for everyone.

Answer (score 8):

If you chose to side with Pagan in the early ending, when the game ends you will be prompted to start a New game. There will be no option to go to open world; rather, the ending of the game encourages you to take the normal path (don't wait for Pagan).